# Passar array de dados da view para o controller Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-rotas

Estou tentando passar um array da minha *view* para um *controller* (ele vai gerar um pdf) em Laravel.
Sei que existe a possibilidade de eu fazer assim:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="get" action={{route('pdf.relatorioPessoa',$dataform['nom_nome'],$dataform['nom_endereco'],$dataform['nom_cidade'])}}>
   <button type="submit">Gerar Relatório</button>
</form>
```

Entretanto este *array* é enorme, tem ao menos 20 campos. Eu teria que criar um parâmetro para cada um deles na rota, além de validar no controler se eles podem ser nulos. Não existe uma forma de eu passar o *array* inteiro pela rota?

Já tentei alterar a parte de rota para:

```
{{route('pdf.relatorioPessoa',[$dataform])}}
```

E resulta: *ErrorException: Array to string conversion*

E sem o [] fala que preciso passar um parâmetro como se não estivesse passando nada.

Comment: Como você está recebendo o parâmetro na `controller`?

Comment: Apenas assim no controller:  public function relatorioPessoa($array){}, ja na rota é Route::get('/pdf/pessoa/{array}','pdfController@relatorioPessoa')->name('pdf.relatorioPessoa');

Comment: E se você utilizar o `request`? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests

Comment: Eu tentei, mas o comando nem chega no controle. O erro ocorre na passagem de parâmetro. São os dois últimos erros citados, conversão de array para string ou só fala que não tem parâmetro. Acho que talvez não exista uma maneira de passar um array inteiro por parâmetro mesmo...

Answer (score 0):

É possível transformar a `array` em um objeto e passar ele.

```js
// Exemplo em JavaScript

var arraySelecionados = {selected: [1, 2, 3, 4]};

axios.post('nome/da/minha/rota', arraySelecionados) ...
```

Definindo a rota algo como:

```php
Route::post('nome/da/minha/rota', 'MinhaController@funcao');
```

E sua Controller:

```php
public function funcao(Request $request){
        $variavel = $request->input('selected');
        // [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

Comment: No caso você mostrou uma variável JavaScript, e para passar minha variável $dataform? tentei passar axios.post('pdf.relatorioPessoa', {{$dataform}}); e deu erro de que espera uma sring e chegou um array. Código do erro: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: O seu `$dataform` é um objeto? Ele precisa ser por exemplo `$dataform = ['selected' => [1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o mais simples seria algo como:

```html
@php
    $route = route('pdf.relatorioPessoa');

    $nome = $dataform['nom_nome'];
    $endereco = $dataform['nom_endereço'];
    $cidade = $dataform['nom_cidade'];
 
    $query_string = "nome=$nome&endereco=$endereco&cidade=$cidade";

    $action = "{$route}?{$query_string}";
@endphp

<form 
   class="form-horizontal"
   method="GET"
   action={{ $action }}
>
```

Comment: Só um comentário informativo:
  
Para gerar relatório o melhor é enviar apenas o id da entidade e no controller realizar toda a construção de relatório. Os dados que você está tentando enviar só é uma boa ideia quando são dados para realizar filtros no backend.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri como enviar um *array* inteiro por parâmetro de jeito simples pessoal. Você precisa usar esta sintaxe

```
['dataform'=>$dataform]<!--O primeiro é o nome que você quer dar para variável(ela vai assim no controller) o segundo é o array-->
```

Também precisa mudar o método do formulário com **@method('get')** e não colocar o método get diretamente.
O código completo fica assim:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action={{route('pdf.relatorioPessoa',['dataform'=>$dataform])}}>
    @method('get')
    <button type="submit">Gerar Relatório</button>
</form>
```

A rota ainda esta declarada como any(para aceitar método get e post), mas com método get apenas também funciona!

```
Route::any('/pdf/pessoa','pdfController@relatorioPessoa')->name('pdf.relatorioPessoa');
```

Espero que ajude pessoas com esta duvida no futuro!